# Need to place the header of the collapsible item at center in Jquery Mobile 1.1.0

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible content like this http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/Ae5CU/

In that the Summary is aligned at the left side. I need to align the Summary at the center.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.ui-collapsible-heading a {text-align:center;}​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the content inside the summary or the header itself?

If its the content the following css seems to do the trick. Althought not fully tested.

Add this to the CSS section in jsFiddle (will just update the summaryid header)

```
​#summaryid .ui-btn-text​ { text-align:center;margin:0px auto; display:inline-block; }​
```

For a global update for all your collapsible headers use

.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-text { text-align:center; margin:0px auto; display:inline-block; }​

The header is being converted into the following HTML output by jQuery Mobile

```
 <h2 id="summaryid" class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-null" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="null" data-mini="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            <span>
                Summary
            </span>
            <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> 
                click to expand contents
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

So walking down the DOM we can find the id 'summaryid' then a child of class 'ui-btn-text' which is the span with the words summary. What you need to do is set the span to appear in the center. To do this with the margin:0px auto and display:inline-block.

Now i have not tested this with smaller resolutions or long headers but this should help you to get started.

Cheers,

Nico